# Recreating Feature generates no text-format related code

Tags: features

- My D7/Panopoly site has 3 text formats: plain_text, panopoly_html_text and panopoly_wysiwyg_text.
- I added Pathologic to the filter list for all text formats; I now need to to capture this to code.
- If I check Text Formats > Plain Text and recreate, relevant code is written to mtms_config.features.filter.inc.
- But when I select "filter panopoly_html_text" and "filter panopoly_wysiwyg_text" from Feature Overrides and recreate, no relevant code gets written!

You can see the Feature code at https://kopy.io/j9hrv .

Why is Features Override not writing config code for these text formats? I've been pulling my hair out for days. (And yes, there's been plenty of cache-clearing involved.) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was simple: that site was running an **old version of Features.** Updating Features made things work as expected.

I'm leaving this up as a reminder to other users. The simplest things can be the easiest to overlook.